# Error converting data type varchar to numeric and overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @Commission decimal(18,2)
select @Commission=percentage from Commission
declare @qry varchar(Max)

set @qry='select 5 +'+@Commission +''

EXEC(@qry)
```

Here

> The Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: I've added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax and text of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's implicit conversion rules makes it attempt to implicitly convert your `varchar` to `decimal`. You need to explicitly convert the `decimal` to `varchar`:

```
set @qry='select 5 +'+ CAST(@FranchiseeCommission as varchar(20))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass values into dynamic SQL as strings.  Instead, learn to use `sp_executesql`:

```
declare @Commission decimal(18, 2);

select @Commission = percentage
from Commission;

declare @qry varchar(Max);

set @qry='select 5 + @Commission';

exec sp_executesql @qry, 'N@Commission decimal(18, 2)', @Commission=@Commission;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @qry='select 5 +'+convert(nvarchar(max),@FranchiseeCommission)+''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SET @qry='select 5 +'+CAST(@FranchiseeCommission AS varchar(30))+''
```

Since your variable is a decimal, you have to cast it as varchar in order to combine it with your string.

Comment: Never cast to varchar without specifying length.

Answer (score 0):

There is always `concat()` if 2012+

```
set @qry=concat('select 5 +',@Commission)
```